# How to create a dynamic timezone field for both display and input?

Tags: timezone

I have customers all over the world.

Is it possible to have a field where you enter the timezone?

Let's say Eastern Standard Time, I enter 8:pm, I'm in Thailand.

So the field would display something like this:

"8:00 PM Monday, in Eastern Time is
7:00 AM Tuesday, in Thailand"

In my backend of view contacts, so I know when to call or not?

Comment: I think it would be fairly easy to write an extension to inject something like that into the contact summary form - do you have php skills?

Comment: Not really, but a little bit..how do I plug PHP in custom fields, I can do it in Drupal, but not in CiviCRM, I'm using D7 with CiviCrm Module

Comment: hmm yeah - I don't think you can do that. You'd need to use civix to fire up a small extension & then use a hook like https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_summary/ to add in a block

Comment: Could I use Javascript? How can I assign custom ID or class to custom fields?

Comment: You could - you normally would create an extension to do that too - it's not hard - start by grabbing Civix https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/ & go on chat.civicrm.org for help

Comment: That chat link doesn't work for me, never has docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix

Comment: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, I registered wiht MatterMOst Chat, dead end, doesn't work

Comment: Hi, can you contact me at mathieu@civicrm.org? I can look into it.